# How to configure vscode to create final var instead of class name for Java when assign statement to new local variable is triggered

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm new with `VSCode` in `Java`. My request is pretty simple, with `Intellij` when it assigns method result to new local variable it generates `final var myVariable` such as follow :

```java
final var employee = new Employee();
```

but in `VSCode` when I use the shortcut it generates

```java
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

Is there any way to generate the same template as `Intellij` ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Currently AFAIK, it's not supported to add final modifier when extracting to a local variable.

But as a workaround, maybe you can try the source action: `Change modifiers to final where possible`.

You can find it in the source actions (in right-click context menu)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, its almost the same result as intellij ^^